# Pandas length mismatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to run this code but it gives me the same error everytime.

```
def concatenate(indir="E:\\HOME\\NBAStats\\PlayByPlay",outfile="E:\\HOME\\NBAStats\\PlayByPlay\\Concatenated.csv",sep='\t'):
        os.chdir(indir)
        filelist=glob.glob("*.csv")
        dflist=[]
        colnames=['game_id', 'data_set', 'date', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'period', 'away_score', 'home_score', 'remaining_time', 'elapsed', 'play_length', 'play_id', 'team', 'event_type', 'assist', 'away', 'home', 'block', 'entered', 'left', 'num', 'opponent', 'outof', 'player', 'points', 'possession', 'reason', 'result', 'steal', 'type', 'shot_distance', 'original_x', 'original_y', 'converted_x', 'converted_y', 'description']
        for filename in filelist:
            print(filename)
            df=pandas.read_table(filename, header=None)
            dflist.append(df)
        concatdf=pandas.concat(dflist,axis=0)
        print(type(concatdf))
        concatdf.columns=colnames
        concatdf.head()
        concatdf.to_csv(outfile,index=False)
```

The error is:

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values
>   have 44 elements

Comment: Did you import the table in the expected format? (44 columns?)

Comment: I think there is no tab separator in some file(s), which is default in `read_table`

Comment: So need set it only - e.g. if comma `df=pandas.read_table(filename, header=None, sep=',')`

Comment: Already tried with sep=','. Same result

Comment: @FabianYing What do you mean? I have imported with read_table but I also tried with csv

Comment: @fede It is possible that `df=pandas.read_table(filename, header=None)` does not always give a dataframe in the right format with 44 columns, but may only have 1 column. For debugging, you can print `print(df.head())` to see whether the `df` is in the format, you expect.

Comment: @FabianYing 'print(df.head())' gives me what I expected '[5 rows x 44 columns] <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>'. The problem I think comes when I append the df to the dflist. In that moment it loses all the columns but I can't concatenate a dataframe. I need an iterable of pandas objects, so a list

Comment: @fede Is that true for every dataframe that is in `dflist`? Also can you confirm which line the ValueError occurs? Is it in   `concatdf=pandas.concat(dflist,axis=0)`.

Comment: @FabianYing since I type read_csv instead of read_table it gives me the same ValueError but saying it expected 46 columns but the data contains jut 44. Unfortunately I can't understand in which line the ValueError occurs. I'll paste the ValueError in an answer here, thanks if you can help I'm learning

Comment: It's important to know where exactly the error occurs. From the error log, it seems your problem is in line 25 with `concatdf.columns=colnames`. It seems `concatdf` only has one column, while you are trying to rename 44 columns. See what `print(concatdf.head())` shows. For debugging purposes, try to get as far as you can without error and see whether the input is as you expect. (Use Jupyter or ipython to execute line by line to see where the error occurs)

Answer (score 0):

This is the Vale error occuring using read_csv instead of read_table

```
>        File "<ipython-input-8-24ad9c1ee739>", line 1, in <module>
>     runfile('C:/Users/Fede/ToConcatenateNBA.py', wdir='C:/Users/Fede')
> 
>   File
> "C:\Users\Fede\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
> line 880, in runfile
>     execfile(filename, namespace)
> 
>   File
> "C:\Users\Fede\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
> line 102, in execfile
>     exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
> 
>   File "C:/Users/Fede/ToConcatenateNBA.py", line 29, in <module>
>     concatenate()
> 
>   File "C:/Users/Fede/ToConcatenateNBA.py", line 25, in concatenate
>     concatdf.columns=colnames
> 
>   File
> "C:\Users\Fede\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
> line 2983, in __setattr__
>     return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
> 
>   File "pandas\_libs\src\properties.pyx", line 65, in
> pandas._libs.lib.AxisProperty.__set__ (pandas\_libs\lib.c:45103)
> 
>   File
> "C:\Users\Fede\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
> line 471, in _set_axis
>     self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
> 
>   File
> "C:\Users\Fede\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
> line 2836, in set_axis
>     (old_len, new_len))
> 
> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 46 elements, new values
> have 44 elements
```

Comment: I solved the problem adding to new columns in colnames. But I don't think it is the best way to fix that. I had to add two empty columns to the file and then delete those